# How to merge cells made by \parbox vertically

Tags: spacing, tex-core, etoolbox, parbox, vspace

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgf,etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\fboxsep0pt
\sbox0{\parbox{1in}{a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a}}
\fbox{\parbox{1in}{a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a}}%the first \parbox
\fbox{\parbox[c][\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0]{1in}{\offinterlineskip%the second \parbox
    \fbox{\parbox{1in}{a\\a\\a}}\\%the third \parbox
    \fbox{\parbox{1in}{a\\a}}\\%the fouth \parbox
    \fbox{\parbox{1in}{a}}%the fifth \parbox
  }}
\par

My question: How to fully fill the second \verb|\parbox| in vertical direction by the third, the fourth, and the fifth \verb|\parbox|s so that they have the same height with the first \verb|\parbox|?(seem like to merge cells vertically)
\vskip 3em

Another question: How to eliminate the "gap" as shown on the attatched figure 2?
\fboxsep0pt
\sbox0{\parbox{1in}{a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a}}
\fbox{\parbox[c]{1in}{a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a}}%the first \parbox
\fbox{\parbox[c][\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0][t]{1in}{%the second \parbox
    \parbox{1in}{a\\a\\a}\hrule%the third \parbox
    \parbox{1in}{a\\a\\}\hrule%the fouth \parbox
    \colorbox{green}{\parbox{1in}{a\vfill\smash{\mbox{}}}}%the fifth \parbox
  }}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: (i) please provide an sketch, what you like to achieve, (ii) is not simpler to write a table with contents of your `\parboxes`?

Comment: I add a picture to illustrate my intention

Comment: Now I'm even more convinced, that this much simpler to do by use of table.

Comment: I mean if there is any way to make the height of inner `\parbox` fill to the bottom of outer \parbox.

Comment: I know, what you mean, but I offer you simpler solution. Since you not liked it, you will have to wait for someone who will be willing to do this on way, how you liked.

Comment: Would you give a MWE for your solution? And would you help me with my second question? Thank you.

Comment: try `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{1em}|}}
    \hline
\multirow{8}{=}{a a a a a a a}
    &           \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & a a a     \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & a a       \\
    \cline{2-2}
    & a         \\
    \cline{2-2}
    &           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Why do LaTeX users keep on trying to achieve stuff with primitives instead of using standard/extended packages?

Comment: @Zarko if you turn your comment into an answer, I'll upvote it!

Comment: No one can help me with my second question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{multirow,
            tabularray} 
\parindent0pt  

\begin{document} 
\section*{First question}
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{1em}|}}     
    \hline 
\multirow{8}{=}{a a a a a a a}     
    &           \\     \cline{2-2}     
    & a a a     \\     \cline{2-2}
    & a a       \\     \cline{2-2}
    & a         \\     \cline{2-2}
    &           \\
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 

\section*{Second question}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={*{2}{Q[l,wd=1em]}},
             }
\SetCell[r=3]{l}    a a a a a a a   
    &   a a a       \\ 
    &   a a         \\
    &   a           \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second example can be solve with `tabular` too, but is more tricky. Simpler is to use use `tabularray` package as is done in above MWE.

With `tabularray` can be solved the first problem too, but result is a bit different:

```
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={*{2}{Q[l,wd=1em]}},
             rowsep=0pt
             }
\SetCell[r=5]{l}    a a a a a a a
    &           \\     
    & a a a     \\     
    & a a       \\     
    & a         \\     
    &           \\
\end{tblr}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solutions! And for my second question, is there any other solution other than using a package?

Comment: @lyl, of course. You can draw this. For example by use of `tikz` package, or `pstrickl` etc. However, solution will not be so simple any more.